# Initializing the weights of a layer from the output of another layer in tensorflow/keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement the paper "learning to segment everything" and I need to set the weights of a layer in the segmentation network using the output of a weight transfer function.

The output of the last layer in the weight transfer fetched using layer.output in Keras is of type 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor' while the weights should be initialized as a numpy array. Any idea how I can set the weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weights are typically stored in Variables. [`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/api_docs/python/tf/assign) operation can be used to assign values (represented as Tensors) to variables. You can see some basic examples of using tf.assign in [session tests](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/991e205a78f67ce21b0918613a45cfd7c3e348fd/tensorflow/python/client/session_test.py#L985). It name there is `state_ops.assign()`.

Just be aware that, like other tensorflow operations, it does not update the value of the variable immediately (unless you are using eager execution). It returns a tensor, that when evaluated (e.g. via `session.run()`), will update the variable.

From your question, I suspect that you might not be 100% clear about tensorflow computation model. The `Tensor` type is a symbolic representation of some value that will be produced only when the computation is actually run (via `session.run()`). You can't really talk about "converting a Tensor to numpy array" because you can't really convert the "result of operation foo" to concrete floats. You have to run the computation to compute the "result of operation foo" to know the concrete numbers. `tf.assign` works in this symbolic space. When using it, you are saying, "whatever the value of this tensor (output of some layer) will be when I run the computation, assign it to this variable".

Answer (score 1):

From what i got from the paper, the weights should be connected to the output of this transform layer let's say it's X. So what you want isn't creating "weights" then initializing the weights with this output X using tf.assign or any other method as this will not be **differentiable**., what you want is to **connect** the output X directly to work as weights in this other graph.

The thing is you can't do this through Keras layers or even tf.layers as this high level api doesn't allow you control this, because as soon as you create a layer in tf.layers or keras it creates it's own weights and you don't want that, you want to use this output X as weights not creating a new weights. So what you can do is easily re-implement whatever layer you want by yourself and use X directly as weights in this layer this will allow the gradient to flow back through this X.